# Different results with AES 128 CBC decryption between NodeJS and Python

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

currently I try to reimplement a network device protocol library which is written in python. In that context I've to handle encrypted and crypted strings. Now, encryption works fine. I get the same result like the python code and the device does also communicate back to me.

Now, I'm currently surpried and confused, that decryption of the same string does result in different length.

I've written 2 samples:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = bytearray([0x09, 0x76, 0x28, 0x34, 0x3f, 0xe9, 0x9e, 0x23, 0x76, 0x5c, 0x15, 0x13, 0xac, 0xcf, 0x8b, 0x02])
iv = bytearray([0x56, 0x2e, 0x17, 0x99, 0x6d, 0x09, 0x3d, 0x28, 0xdd, 0xb3, 0xba, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x2e, 0x6f, 0x58])
enc = bytearray([0x38, 0x31, 0x40, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x43, 0xb2, 0x42, 0x85, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7b, 0x26, 0x13, 0x78, 0x32, 0x5a, 0xc3, 0x6a, 0x1c, 0x26, 0xbc, 0xc2, 0xde, 0x50, 0xdd, 0x38, 0x63, 0xb0, 0xc4, 0x64]);

print str(enc).encode('hex');
aes = AES.new(str(key), AES.MODE_CBC, str(iv));
payload = aes.decrypt(str(enc));
print str(payload).encode('hex');
```

I get the result

```
3831406c6143b24285f400107b261378325ac36a1c26bcc2de50dd3863b0c464
0200000028a01d795f13946895860a58ccf98047000000000000000000000000
```

The equivalent code in nodeJS

```
'use strict'

var crypto = require('crypto');

var key = new Array(0x09, 0x76, 0x28, 0x34, 0x3f, 0xe9, 0x9e, 0x23, 0x76, 0x5c, 0x15, 0x13, 0xac, 0xcf, 0x8b, 0x02);
var iv = new Array(0x56, 0x2e, 0x17, 0x99, 0x6d, 0x09, 0x3d, 0x28, 0xdd, 0xb3, 0xba, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x2e, 0x6f, 0x58);
var enc = new Array(0x38, 0x31, 0x40, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x43, 0xb2, 0x42, 0x85, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x10, 0x7b, 0x26, 0x13, 0x78, 0x32, 0x5a, 0xc3, 0x6a, 0x1c, 0x26, 0xbc, 0xc2, 0xde, 0x50, 0xdd, 0x38, 0x63, 0xb0, 0xc4, 0x64);

console.log(new Buffer(enc));
var aes = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-128-cbc", new Buffer(key), new Buffer(iv));
var payload = aes.update(new Buffer(enc));
console.log(new Buffer(payload));
```

Throw the result

```
<Buffer 38 31 40 6c 61 43 b2 42 85 f4 00 10 7b 26 13 78 32 5a c3 6a 1c 26 bc c2 de 50 dd 38 63 b0 c4 64>
<Buffer 02 00 00 00 28 a0 1d 79 5f 13 94 68 95 86 0a 58>
```

So, whats wrong here? Why there is a part missing in the encrypted data?

Comment: Wild guess, try this in nodejs : aes.setAutoPadding(false);

Comment: @Boris, you made my day! I think that I had already tried it, but apparently I had overlooked something. Thank you!

Comment: Have a nice day ! ;)

Comment: Okay ... found my mistake, was really stupid: Set auto padding after I'd created already the encrypted string. Made more sense, set if before doing any action ^^